# IF AND OR SWITCH in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, switch-statement

I have made a basic formula which calculates the number of staff required to process sales in any given hour on a typical working day.

Now I am trying to create a formula in Google sheets which checks the number of staff required to process the sales VS the actual number of staff who have been rostered on.

I have one row with the predicted hourly sales, one row with the number of staff required to process the sales, and one row with the actual number of staff rostered for every given hour.

I need to create a formula which checks the number of staff required vs the number of staff actually rostered:

- IF there is insufficient staff, it will return "Insufficient".
- IF the number of staff rostered is sufficient (within 10% less of, or 25% more of the predicted sales), return "Sufficient".
- IF there is more than 25% more staff than necessary, return "Overstaffed".

I've searched this, but I am unable to find a suitable example / wrap my head around them and customize them to suit my needs.

I've got reasonable experience programming with PHP, Python, Java, and JavaScript, however, in this instance, I am strictly limited (by my employer) to creating a roster in Google sheets.

**I have tried the following:**

```
=IF(F13 = "", "", IF(F15 = "", "", IF(F15 < F13, "Understaffed", IF(F15 >= F13, "Enough Staff", ELSEIF(F15 > (F13*1.3), "Too many staff")))))
```

**And I have also tried:**

```
=SWITCH(G15, G15 < G13, "Under", G15 >= G13, "Fine", G15 > G13*1.3, "Over")
```

But they do not work correctly.

Can someone assist me in this? TIA

[image: see img]

Comment: Thanks for the help! It wprks fine now.

I've often found it more difficult to write and interpret formulas in MS Excel / GSheets. It's not as easy to set specific defining paramaters to reject or accept data conditionally.

I've always used nested if statements, or && / AND, in PHP / Python, which seems to be more basic than Sheets.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SWITCH(G15, G15 < G13, "Under", G15 >= G13, "Fine", G15 > G13*1.3, "Over")
```

In your second SWITCH formula, the second condition is true for both the second and third condition and so the third condition is never reached. Flip the second and third condition placements.

```
=if(count(F13, F15)=2, IFS(F15<F13, "under", F15>F13*1.3, "over", F15>=F13, "enough"), "")
```

[image]